# Use git repository as private NPM registry

Tags: npm, npm-publish, git-repo, npm-registry, npm-private-modules

Want to use git repository as a private npm registry to publish my own npm packages.
I have tried with the `publishConfig` and `npm config set registry <>`.
When I am setting the npm registry with `npm config set registry <>` and try to login with `npm login` it throws an erro :

`npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! Registry returned 403 for PUT on https://github.com/<project>/-/user/org.couchdb.user:<username>
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     *****-31T09_44_15_043Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add authentication through .npmrc file, that could work if it is authentication problem.

Please find the below links to learn about setting npm config through .npmrc

1.https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/node-packaged-modules-and-npm-registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-EncodingCredentialsonWindowsusingPowershell

2.https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc